# Refresh a particular div when I click on that div.Without reloading the whole page.I specifically want it using onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function () {
        j(".refresh").everyTime(2000, function (i) {
            j.ajax({
                url: "refresh.php",
                cache: true,
                success: function (html) {
                    j(".refresh").html(html);
                }
            })
        })
    });

    j('.refresh').css({
        color: ""
    });
});
```

```php
<?php
    echo time();
?>
```

It works for refreshing page after particular time interval .I want this to be working after I click on particular div.

Comment: then make `j(".refresh").everyTime(2000, function (i) {` line into a onclick function which you can easily find on here or on a google search

Comment: It would be better if you provide me the code.Can you provide me the code its really high time to complete the project.Please provide me the code so that I can use almost directly as onclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your code in a `click` handler. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(".refresh").everyTime(2000, refreshDiv)
    j('#myDiv').click(refreshDiv);

    j('.refresh').css({
        color: ""
    });

    function refreshDiv() {
        j.ajax({
            url: "refresh.php",
            cache: true,
            success: function (html) {
                j(".refresh").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Note that I extracted the logic in to its own function so it can be called from different parts of your code. I also removed the pointless duplicate DOMReady handler.

Comment: Its working when I click on the div ...but it keeps on refreshing after two seconds just like timer....I want to refresh only after I click on the div

Comment: In that case simply comment out the call to your `everyTime` function.

Comment: Then you must have another call to it somewhere in your code. There is nothing in the provided sample that would cause that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple one

But you need to modify it

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.refresh').on('click', function(){

            $.ajax({
                url: "refresh.php",
                cache: true,
                success: function (html) {
                    j(".refresh").html(html);
                }
            });

        });

    });
```